# Socket API in TCP

Tags: computer-networks, tcp, api-design

[image]

According to me Statement S1 and S2 is True while S3 is False.
The Solution says 'S3' is correct ? Am I Wrong ? Kindly help with explanation .

I know Connect() in TCP is used by the client side for generating a request to server while it gets the destination address and port no. as a part of address structure .

Comment: The wording of this question is questionable. "Socket API in TCP" is nonsense: TCP doesn't have a socket API, a particular OS has a socket API that supports TCP sockets.

Comment: @reinierpost Yea that's true ! Also according to my knowledge Connect() is used to perform active open by the application process(to whom it want's to communicate), while the destination address is filled by the client side in address argument , it leaves the local information to the OS to fill but it does not assign a free local port number to a socket (Bind() does that) . What is you opinion regarding statement S3 ?